# How can I re-fill form fields that a user filled out after I've redirected them back to the form when there was an error?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, autofill

Short version:

- I have a form with over 100 fields and each field has server-side validation.
- I have the form working and data being submitted successfully; I'm even redirecting them back to the form when there are errors with the validation, and displaying what error in specific happened.
- When they're redirected back to the (massive) form, all of their data is gone and they need to type it again.

I have already thought of a couple ways of answering my own question, but they aren't the most elegant solutions out there.

My current thought process is: save all of their inputted data as $_SESSION variables -- and whenever they load the form, do an `if` statement around each input, as such;

```
if(isset($_SESSION['foo_data'])) {

    echo "<input type='text' name='foo' value='$_SESSION["foo_data"]'>";

} else {

    echo "<input type='text' name='foo' placeholder='Enter your text here...'>";

}
```

This method will **work**, but it also involves an immensely tedious definition of 140+ session variables, followed by an even more tedious and immense creating if/else statements around **EVERY** form field.

Is there any better way to do this?

Additional info: using plain php, no frameworks of any kind.

Comment: I would have an array() holding the form fields, then a loop, to build the form (with a check for session  values)

Comment: Why redirect if there are errors in the first place?

Comment: One Trick Pony: I'm currently doing validation in a separate PHP file all-together. Would you mind explaining how validating in the same file would change things?

Comment: Keep your checks in the separate file. I'm just saying the you could display the form after checks fail, this way you keep submitted $_POST data and avoid use of sessions. No need for redirect unless the form is submitted successfully

Comment: Errr, doesn't that leave me in an identical situation? (Having to use 140 `if / else` statements for `isset($_POST['foo_data']` to echo out different inputs, just the same as I would have to do with session variables).

Comment: Perhaps it does, but read Dagon's comment about keeping the keys inside an array and generating the HTML while looping the array. I was just suggesting you don't redirect if you don't need to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are unnecessary. Your basic plan should be:

- Get variables from $_POST()
- Validate form values.
- Create an array with the values that passed validation.
- Use the array to fill the values when redirected to the form.

Before I started using CodeIgniter, I used to use `if` statements to validate and generate error messages like this:

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['email'])){
    if ($this->verifyInput($_POST['email'], 6)){
        $fill['email'] = $_POST['email'];//$fill is the array of values that passed validation
    } else $tally++;//$tally keeps a running count of the total number of erors
}
```

I make a function call to `$this->verifyInput` which accepts the field value and the type of validation to perform--in this case it's 6, which indicates email. Here's my validation function:

```
function verifyInput($input, $type){
    if ($type == 0)     $pattern =  '/^1$/';//just the number 1
    elseif ($type == 1) $pattern =  '/^[0-9]+$/';//just integers
    elseif ($type == 2) $pattern =  '/^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü]+$/';//just letters
    elseif ($type == 3) $pattern =  '/^[0-9A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü]+$/';//integers & letters
    elseif ($type == 4) $pattern =  '/^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-ú0-9àÀÜü\s()\/\'":\*,.;\-!?&#$@]{1,1500}$/';//text
    elseif ($type == 5) $pattern =  '/^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü0-9\']+[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü0-9 \'\-\.]+$/';//name
    elseif ($type == 6) $pattern = '/^.+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,}$/';//e-mail
    elseif ($type == 7) $pattern = '/^((\(0?[1-9][0-9]\))|(0?[1-9][0-9]))?[ -.]?([1-9][0-9]{3})[ -.]?([0-9]{4})$/';//brazilian phone
    if (preg_match($pattern, $input) == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Once the validation is done, I use the `$fill` array to prefill the form for each field:

```
<input class="field" type="text" name="email" value = "<?php echo $fill['email']; ?>"/>
```

You should also make sure that `$fill` is iniciated with empty values such as `$fill['email']='';` or check to make sure the values are set before filling the input tags:

```
<input class="field" type="text" name="email" value = "<?php if(isset($fill['email'])) echo $fill['email']; ?>"/>
```

These are just general guidelines that you can adapt to your needs, but I found this to be a convenient way to handle it.

Comment: That works :) Thanks Pe de Leao! Out of curiosity (because I started learning it this week, and can't really tell how I like it yet) how do you like CodeIgniter VS flat PHP, in particular when it comes to forms & form validation?