# Keep data from inputs after failed validation in PHP

Tags: php, validation

Here's the situation: registration.php with inputs (like firstname, lastname, password) and registrationErrors.php - having self-written error-checks and returning the type of error to the initial registration.php, where it is shown to the user.

In case one of my self-written error occurs, I'd like to save the inputs (registration.php) the user has already done and only clear the input with the error in it.

I have seen a couple of posts having the same problem - but mine's slightly different. Since the data is sent to

```
<form action="registrationErrors.php" method="post" ...>
```

, the suggestion

```
value="<?php echo isset($_POST["firstname"]) ? $_POST["firstname"] : ''; ?>"
```

doesn't work, since it would have to be sent to:

```
<form action="registration.php"...>
```

Any idea how to keep my structure of the two php-files and still have the already-input data saved?

Comment: Put the validation in the same script, or include the processing script in the validation script if it worked. Also, the pseudo code you have would be open to XSS injections.... You also could do client side validation, or AJAX to verify the data prior to form submission. You still would need to do server side validation but should be minimal for user after that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I re-fill form fields that a user filled out after I've redirected them back to the form when there was an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395636/how-can-i-re-fill-form-fields-that-a-user-filled-out-after-ive-redirected-them)

Comment: ...to build on what @user3783243 suggested, you can simply submit the form using Ajax all together (not just for the validation part but also for handling the data if the validation passed) and redirect the user to somewhere else if the form was successfully handled. Then you don't need an extra round trip to the server just for the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use session variables to do what you want

PHP (submission form)

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!-- other statements -->

<form action="registrationErrors.php" method="post" ...>
<!-- other inputs -->
<input name=firstname value="<?= $_SESSION['firstname']  ?? '' ?>"
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

registrationErrors.php

```
<?php session_start();

$_SESSION["firstname"]=$_POST["firstname"]) ?? '';

// the above is equivalent to:
// $_SESSION["firstname"] = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';

// other statements , error checking, etc

?>
```

- make sure you have put `session_start();` at the start of all related php scripts
- please do the same for lastname, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can save data on session in a file registrationErrors.php and then retrieve it on registration.php.
Also You can send data using GET parameter to registration.php.

```
value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION["firstname"]) ? $_SESSION["firstname"] : ''; ?>"
```

this will work.

OR even

```
value="<?php echo isset($_GET["firstname"]) ? $_GET["firstname"] : ''; ?>"
```

this will work